# See Every Configuration Field (a Schema?) for Kubernetes REST Objects

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

I'm new to Kubernetes (K8s).  It's my understanding that in order to "do things" in a kubernetes cluster, we interact with a kuberentes REST API endpoint and create/update/delete objects.  When these objects are created/updated/deleted K8s will see those changes and take steps to bring the system in-line with the state of your objects.

In other words, you tell K8s you want a "deployment object" with container image `foo/bar` and 10 replicas and K8s will create 10 running pods with the `foo/bar` image.  If you update the deployment to say you want 20 replicas, K8s will start more pods.

My Question: Is there a canonical description of all the possible configuration fields for these objects?  That is -- tutorials liks [this one](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment) do a good job of describing the simplest possible configuration to get an object like a deployment working, but now I'm curious what else it's possible to do with deployments that go beyond these hello world examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a canonical description of all the possible configuration fields for these objects?

Yes, there is the [Kubernetes API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/) e.g. for [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/deployment-v1/).

But when developing, the easiest way is to use `kubectl explain <resource>` and navigate deeper, e.g:

```
kubectl explain Deployment.spec
```

and then deeper, e.g:

```
kubectl explain Deployment.spec.template
```